# Count in column only rows present

Tags: google-sheets

I don't know how to say in language, but I need what I realize in this [spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zP2i-Tx3QKEZjU4SbiyJg4xWwtTZt9seDDzSrRxlOjg)

In attached spreadsheet there are two sheets: "How it is now" and "How it should be".

I use this formula in other sheets, but now it doesn't work correctly:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(B:B); IF(ROW(A:A)=1; "N°"; (IF(ISBLANK($C:C); "-"; (IF($C:C=1; SUM($C:$C)+1; (SUM($C:$C)+1 & " - " & SUM($C:$C)+$C:C))))))))
```

Please remove the trailing `FALSE` text in the first column after the cell range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(B:B)=1;"N°";IF(LEN(B:B);IF(LEN(C:C);IF(C:C>1;(SUMIF(ROW(B:B);">"&ROW(B:B);C:C)+1)&" - ";)&SUMIF(ROW(B:B);">="&ROW(B:B);C:C);"-");)))`

Comment: Beautiful. Splendid. Genius.

Comment: Please, @AdamL, can you help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696283/sum-values-of-the-column-circular-dependency